# Eclipse highlighting for dark color schemes

Tags: eclipse

I use Solarized Dark color scheme for Eclipse, but as shown in the following screenshot, the light highlighting on light text renders it unreadable. I've tried changing the settings in Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Occurrences to different colors such as red, yellow, etc. but it seems to have no effect. How do I change the highlighting on for dark color schemes to make the text readable?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OS X, try changing your system Highlight color in **System Preferences > General** to something with more contrast.